# Issue with use of fullscreenControl feature

Tags: leaflet

I just implement the fullscreenControl on two sites I developed/maintain. The feature works great on [the first one](https://www.txfannin.org/view_large_map/cem/33.644778/-95.945042/allens-chapel-cemetery) I added, but [not the second](https://www.msholmes.org/view_large_map/cem/33.128760/-90.260435/antioch-mb-church-cemetery). I've triple checked the coding of both sites and they are identical. It's not that complicated... add 'fullscreenControl: true' to the map initialization and one cdn load to the css and js. Any thoughts as to why the problem.

Comment: This is the map initialization code... `let map = L.map('map_canvas_lg', {center: [CO_CENTER_LAT, CO_CENTER_LON], fullscreenControl: true, zoomControl: false, zoom: 10, minZoom: 9, maxZoom: 11, layers: [streets, county]});`

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. In my _java_loader I was loading a Leaflet_ajax file twice.